# How to use PHP variable with a Wordpress Shortcode of AAWP Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I use Wordpress with the GeneratePress Theme. A feature of this theme called "Elements" let you write php code which will be executed on a specific hook. These Hooks can be found here: https://docs.generatepress.com/article/hooks-visual-guide/

I use the AAWP plugin to show an amazon bestseller list. I want to get the Wordpress category and place it into the bestseller parameter of the aawp shortcode to get Products for the respective categories.

I already read posts here about using php variables in wordpress shortcodes but it seems that something other than the syntax is the problem.

I have this code

```
<?php

 $categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty($categories ) ) {
    $category = $categories[0];
    $name = $category->name;
    $bestseller = 'bestseller="'.$name.'"';
    $shortCode = '[aawp grid="3" '.$bestseller.' items="3" filter_items="20" orderby="percentage_saved" order="desc"]';
    
echo do_shortcode($shortCode); 
}

?>
```

The amazon list doesnt appear on my page. It seems that the "bestseller" parameter is neccesarry in order to get shown.
The variable doesnt really get recognized.
When I remove the variable and replace it with a hardcoded bestseller parameter its working fine.

When I use this code:

```
<?php

 $categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty($categories ) ) {
    $category = $categories[0];
    $name = $category->name;
    $bestseller = 'bestseller="'.$name.'"';
    $shortCode = '[aawp template="angebot-vertical" grid="3" bestseller="'.$name.'" items="3" filter_items="20" orderby="percentage_saved" order="desc"]';
    
echo do_shortcode($shortCode); 
}

?>
```

It seems that the bestseller value doesnt get read but the "empty" bestseller parameter is enough to show the amazon list, so it just shows random products.

How can I make this work? I just want to place a variable as a value into the "bestseller" parameter. Should be the easiest thing but it doesnt work in the scope of this GeneratePress Elements Hook whith the AAWP shortcode

Comment: Have you verified whether `$categories = get_the_category();` actually returned what you think it should? Make debug output of that using `var_dump`, and verify that you actually got the data there, that you think you should have.

Comment: I don't see the [add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) call that registers your hook function. Nor do I see the hook function itself; you have some code that isn't in a function in your question. You need to [structure this code as action code](https://docs.generatepress.com/article/using-hooks/). If you've already done that, please [edit] your question to include all that code.

Comment: I already checked it and it does retun just the category name. The $name variable is just a string with the category name when I output it.

The thing is that this code is written inside the backend of Wordpress under the "Elements" section of the Theme. It will already beeing added by the theme. You can do whatever PHP you want and it normaly works, but not with the shortcode of AAWP unfrotunately

Answer (score 0):

You're possibly not getting what you believe you need back from `get_the_category()`. Assuming you're able to get the category id you can use [`get_cat_name()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_cat_name/) function to return the category name.

```
<?php

 $cat_name = get_cat_name($category_id);

if ( ! empty($cat_name) ) {
    $shortCode = '[aawp template="angebot-vertical" grid="3" bestseller="'.$cat_name.'" items="3" filter_items="20" orderby="percentage_saved" order="desc"]';
    
echo do_shortcode($shortCode); 
}

?>
```